# How do we define the distance between two lines or planes that intersect?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, analytic-geometry

How do we define the distance between two lines or planes that intersect? Since it cannot be defined injectively for every point, is it defined at all in such a case?

Comment: As long as I'm aware the distance is zero if they're intersecting.

Comment: Hi: I've changed your title to something useful. You should do something similar in the future if you want your questions to have attention. I also changed the tags to more relevant ones.

Comment: The canon for a distance is that of the Grassmann manifold, related to the smallest principal angle. Clearly not zero unless one subspace is contained in the other (it is unrelated to whether they intersect or not). Better thus to ask: How to define distance between two subspaces that have some transverse directions?

Answer (score 9):

As noted in comments and other answers, the distance between them in the usual sense is $0$. Another way to measure "how far apart" they are is to use the angle between them. That would be $0$ if they were identical and $\pi/2$ if they were perpendicular. Perhaps that  would be useful in your application.

Comment: That definition is most useful when all the planes/line are required to be subspaces, so that when the angle between them (what's called the distance in this case) is zero, the two things are identical. For arbitrary lines in 3-space, for instance, you can embed them as the $w = 1$ plane, join each to the origin in 4-space and compute the angle between the resulting subspaces using Ethan's method.

Answer (score 5):

In this situation it is better to use the distance on the Grassmann manifold. First, given a set $E \subset \mathbb R^p$ and $v \in \mathbb R^p$, let
$$
d(v,E)=\inf \big\{\lVert v-w \rVert: w \in E \big\}.
$$
Then, given subspaces $E,F \subset \mathbb R^p$, we define
$$
d(E,F)=\max \bigg\{ \max_{v \in E, \lVert v \rVert=1} d(v,F), \max_{w \in F, \lVert w \rVert=1} d(w,E) \bigg\}.
$$

*PS: We cannot use angles without anything else simply because they do not define a distance!*

Comment: Can you explain this distance geometrically?

Comment: For example, when $E$ and $F$ are $1$-dimensional spaces in $\mathbb R^2$ we have $d(E,F)=\sin\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between $E$ and $F$.

Answer (score 2):

The distance between two sets that intersect is always $0$.

Answer (score 2):

In a metric space, given a distance function $d$ on a space $X$, it is customary to define the distance between two nonempty subsets $A,B$ of $X$ as $d(A,B)=\inf(\{d(a,b)\mid (a,b)\in A\times B\})$.

In the special case of ordinary Euclidean distance, and two subsets that share a point $x$, the minimum would be attained by $d(x,x)=0$.

But using this definition, two sets that are disjoint can also have $d(A,B)=0$. For example, if $A=\{(a,0)\mid 0<a<1\}$ and $B=\{(1,0)\}$.

Comment: Reading some of the other answers, I think I misunderstood the intent of the question! At the time I only through to improve upon the existing answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson ah I wrote min... duh. Thanks, that’s obviously what I wanted.

Comment: In your last example, $A$ and $B$ are not subsets of the same space, so distance is undefined. Did you mean $B = \{(1,0)\}$ ?

Comment: @mr_e_man Yeah! At first I had made it an example in $\mathbb R$ but then I thought putting it in the plane would be more welcome... but I neglected to convert that one :/